# How to loop through 1 CPT with 2 Taxonomies

Tags: customization, taxonomy

I have a CPT (Products) which has 2 taxonomies (Industry and department)

I have the loop which delivers a "Product by Industry" which works

Industry 1
• result 1
• result 2

Industry 2
• result 1
• result 2

(see below)

```
<?php
$post_type = 'products';
$tax = 'industry';
$tax_terms = get_terms($tax);

if ($tax_terms) {
    foreach ($tax_terms  as $tax_term) {
        $args=array(
            'post_type' => $post_type,
            "$tax" => $tax_term->slug,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'caller_get_posts'=> 1
        );

        $my_query = null;
        $my_query = new WP_Query($args);

        if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
            echo '<h3>' . $tax_term->name .'</h3>';
            while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
                ?>
                <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
                <?php
            endwhile;
        }
        wp_reset_query();
    }
}
```

... but what I want is for each result to be prefixed with it's department name

ie.

Industry 1
• (department) result 1
• (department) result 2

Industry 2
• (department) result 1
• (department) result 2

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I made a mistake in the name of the 2nd taxonomy in my original question above. It now reads "department".

Comment: Just a note here, please make sure that your code is correct before posting so that no one wastes their time answering incorrect information. It is frustrating answering a question on what you see just to be told it is a mistake. In most cases I simply abandon such questions

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use [wp_get_post_terms()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms).

- **If a product is always associated to only one category** – which has no child if hierarchical – (what I understand from your example), adding below snippet within your `while` loop should do it (not tested).

  ```
  <?
  $cat = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'department' );
  echo '<span>(' . $cat->name . ')</span>';
  ?>
  ```
- **If however a product can have several categories**, it's not much more complicated. Above `$cat` will have to be `$cats` – just add a foreach loop to go throught it. In this case you may also want to specify the 3rd parameter of `wp_get_post_terms()`, which is by default the array `$wp_gpt_args=array('order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'name', 'fields' => 'all')`. You will find the various options in the Codex article on [wp_get_object_terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_object_terms#Argument_Options), that is actually called by `wp_get_post_terms()` and share the same arguments.

---

### EDIT 24/10/2014

I've modified the snippet above with the correct taxonomy name and added the non hierarchical condition to the first point.

As it seems you don't need the full object to be returned, I added in the snippet below one argument so that the function will only return terms' names. From your comments, I can imagine `$cat` will now be an array of strings containing both parents and children terms.

To **only display the top parent terms**, you can apply either the trick suggested [here](https://surefirewebservices.com/how-to-display-the-parent-term-from-a-custom-taxonomy-on-a-post-that-belongs-to-multiple-terms/) or the idea behind it, which would give the following:

```
<?
$wp_gpt_args = array( 'fields' => 'names' ); 
$deps = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'department', $wp_gpt_args );
$top_dep = $deps[0]; //i.e. the first line of $deps array
echo '<span>(' . $top_dep . ')</span>';
?>
```

Comment: I made a mistake in the name of the 2nd taxonomy in my original question above. It now reads "department". Yes each product is associated with one department (previous "category") however the taxonomy "department" is Hierarchical so it may have a parent/child. Not sure if that means I need the 2nd option with the foreach loop. I tried the first solution and it just returned empty brackets before product name.

Comment: ... so I tried the second option and it works! thanks. The only problem is that I would only like to show the first level (parents) of the "department" taxonomy. Advice?

Comment: See the edited answer